# Docker Remote API - Pull/Create image not working

Tags: docker

Okay so I have enabled managing the docker daemon over HTTP by starting the daemon as follows:

```
/usr/bin/docker -d -H fd:// -H=0.0.0.0:2376
```

I can create containers and remove them via the Remote API (i.e other calls are working fine) but if I try and pull an image it errors as follows:

```
curl -v -X POST http://localhost:2376/images/create?from=ubuntu
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 2376 (#0)
> POST /images/create?from=ubuntu HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: localhost:2376
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Thu, 01 Oct 2015 09:01:02 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
{"status":"Downloading from http://"}
{"errorDetail":{"message":"Get http://: http: no Host in request URL"},"error":"Get http://: http: no Host in request URL"}
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Anyone know what the answer is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah looks like it was a typo in the parameter name

```
"from" -> "fromImage"
```

Basically you get this error if the query parameters are missing.

Also make sure you set tag=latest otherwise it downloads all ubuntu images!